# Intellij idea upload changes to subversion repository

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I checked out a maven project from a remote folder in an svn repository using Intellij Idea and opened it as a maven project

I have made some changes locally. now how do i push these changes to the remote folder again

I am confused between the integrate changes and the commit changes option, please help

There is an upload to server option in the commit dialog box,
but it is asking for an ftp host i don't know about that,

I just imported it using the http url something like this http://107.108.70.64/svn/folder1/folder2

Comment: Does `ctrl k` allow you to commit your changes?

Comment: Yeah it allows but i thought commiting from there would only commit to my local computer not the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik subversion doesn't support local repositories (unless you have explicitly installed a subversion server on your local machine), so commiting will indeed commit to the central repository.

It contrast, other source control systems (such as `git`) do operate in a way where you may first `commit` to a local repo and then `push` to the remote one.

Comment: yeah u r right i checked just now, i was fooled initially because to check quickly i just shifted a line of code to a newline and commited but i couldn't see it in the central repo.